# How to count the number of the resulting rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the total number of rows in the result but my query only shows the records but is not counting them.

I used the count function but it didn't work.

```
SELECT BOM.STYLE_ID,
       BOM.SEASON_ID,
       (CASE WHEN bom.Content_class = upper('ART') THEN 
             (CASE WHEN bom.Mat_ref_id IN (SELECT mat_ref_id
                                           FROM iplexmat_material_parm
                                           WHERE artwrk_type = 'EMB') THEN count(Mat_ref_id)
                       ELSE '' END)
            END) AS EMBRO,
       (CASE
             WHEN bom.Mat_ref_id IN
                    (SELECT mat_ref_id
                     FROM iplexmat_material_parm
                     WHERE artwrk_type = 'PRT') THEN count(Mat_ref_id)
             ELSE 0
        END) AS PRINTINGG
FROM IPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL BOM
WHERE CONTENT_CLASS = 'ART'
AND Style_id = 'S1407LHFFR029L'
GROUP BY BOM.STYLE_ID,
         bom.Content_class,
         BOM.SEASON_ID,
         Mat_ref_id;
```

what I want is the total number of rows to be displayed in the query when the given parameters in the query returns true. So there should be only one row as a result. Null values should not be included.

Comment: We need some sample data and desired outcome to understand what you are trying to achieve. You have one select with 2 sub-selects in the middle, and I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: There are several strange things here: `Null values should not be included.` what null values? A row is a row. Since you use `GROUP BY` only a *single* row can have nulls in all the `ID` columns. `count(Mat_ref_id) ELSE '' END` A count is a number, not a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Explain the actual problem, not how you tried to solve it. You have a BOM table and you want to count what, parts? You don't need upper-casing or nested queries in `SELECT` for that. You can probably simplify the query a lot by converting it to left joins between the BOM and Part tables. Once you do that, you can generate grand totals by adding a `WITH ROLLUP` statement after `GROUP BY`

Comment: The two `where artwrk_type = '...'` statements can be replaced with a single `artwrk_type IN ('PRT','EMB')` in the overall `WHERE` clause. `artwrk_type` should appear in the SELECT statement too. The two type values could be converted to columns using `PIVOT`

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using `cte` or without cte - `COUNT(1) OVER()`.

This approach with cte:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID,
   (CASE WHEN bom.Content_class = upper('ART') THEN 
        (case when bom.Mat_ref_id in (select mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm where artwrk_type = 'EMB') then 
            count(Mat_ref_id) ELSE '' END)end) AS EMBRO,

        (case when bom.Mat_ref_id in (select mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm where artwrk_type = 'PRT') THEN 
        count(Mat_ref_id) ELSE 0 END) AS PRINTINGG
FROM IPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL BOM
WHERE CONTENT_CLASS = 'ART' AND Style_id = 'S1407LHFFR029L'
GROUP BY BOM.STYLE_ID, bom.Content_class,BOM.SEASON_ID,Mat_ref_id
)
SELECT 
* 
, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte) -- Number of rows
FROM cte
```

A simple example:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE 
(
    Col1 VARCHAR(10),
    Col2 INT,
    Col3 INT
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable
(
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3
)
VALUES
 ('A',         10,       20)
,('A',         11,       30)
,('A',         12,       40)
,('A',         12,       60)

-- Without cte:
SELECT 
* 
, COUNT(1) OVER() OverallRowCount
FROM @TestTable tt
```

**UPDATE(thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos ). This approach without cte**:

```
SELECT 
  BOM.STYLE_ID
, BOM.SEASON_ID
, (CASE WHEN bom.Content_class = upper('ART') THEN 
    (case when bom.Mat_ref_id in (select mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm where artwrk_type = 'EMB') 
        then count(Mat_ref_id) ELSE '' END)end) AS EMBRO
, (case when bom.Mat_ref_id in (select mat_ref_id from iplexmat_material_parm 
    where artwrk_type = 'PRT') THEN 
    count(Mat_ref_id) ELSE 0 END) AS PRINTINGG
,  COUNT(1) OVER() OverallRowCount
FROM IPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL BOM
WHERE CONTENT_CLASS = 'ART' AND Style_id = 'S1407LHFFR029L'
GROUP BY BOM.STYLE_ID, bom.Content_class,BOM.SEASON_ID,Mat_ref_id
```

Comment: Even that can be avoided using `COUNT(*) OVER()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for great advice. It is really great. I've updated an answer.